# Recover Kazam .movie.mux files

Tags: desktop-recording, kazam

Sometimes when Kazam crashes during saving a recording, it leaves behind its recorded video data -- an empty .movie file, and a large .movie.mux file.

I don't know how to transcode a Kazam .movie.mux file into a playable format like MP4 / WebM / OGV. Is it possible to recover these files?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer

This tool solves exactly this problem. Worked for me. There are a few simple steps involved, instructions are enclosed. You need a short properly saved video on the same machine with the same kazam to use as input so it knows what the headers should look like. And you get the mp4 from the movie.mux.